# ascii heart in c++ windows 10 not displaying

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ascii, windows-10

I'm working on a poker game in c++ using Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 10. When i use the following code to assign suits to my cards the console displays all question marks in the place of the suits.

```
void printHand(Card hand[])
{

    const string SUIT = "\3\4\5\6";
    const string RANK = "23456789TJQKA";

    cout << "Your hand is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << RANK[hand[i].ranks] << SUIT[hand[i].suits] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When I change the suits to other characters I get the right characters like question marks, colons... When I run a for loop to show all Ascii characters, the first 32 characters display as control characters like it doesn't recognize the font.

My question is whether this is because of Visual Studio 2013 Express, Windows 10, or my machine.

Comment: What makes you think `\3` encodes a suit? What is the source of your expectation that this will work?

Comment: Character code 3 is the "OEM" code for a heart.

Comment: Try a different font in your command window.  You can test by typing `echo `, followed by holding down the control key and the D key (this will show as `echo ^D`) then hit enter.  You should see the diamond symbol.  If not, change the properties on the command window and pick a different font.

Comment: echo isn't in C++, but I cout'ed it and it displayed ^D, not a diamond. my console only has three font options and that's how it displays in all three.

Answer (score 3):

Check the checkbox in Properties that says "Use the old console" or something like that (Mine was in swedish). That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you must check:

- Make sure your console is using Code Page 437
- Failing that, make sure your program's locale is the default "C" locale.

Let us know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Code Page 437 and my program is in the Visual Studio folder on my C:\.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. What else have you changed from the defaults? Are you running it from the IDE?

Comment: I haven't changed anything. This is for a class and my instructor can't answer this either. It's more of a nuisance right now since I'm just using other symbols for my suits. The use of Visual Studio is plug and play.

Comment: @ARockwell `program locale is "C"` is a completely different thing than your program file being on the C: drive.

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` and add a `std::cout << GetConsoleOutputCP() << "\n";` to verify that VS isn't changing the CP on you.

Comment: @Dúthomhas when I do that the console displays 437. Where can I check to see if the program locale is "C"?

Comment: If you aren't changing it then it is. There is some other environmental factor changing things, but I can't think what it might be. Did you check that the console font is set to something that has those glyphs, like "Lucida Console"?